# Strange behavior of std::string as an argument of a member function

Tags: c++, object, compilation, member, undefined-behavior

I have a class:

```
class MyClass

{
    char *filename1;
    char *filename2;
public:
    void setFilename1(std::string str)
    {
        filename1 = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str())
    }
    void setFilename2(std::string str))
    {
        filename2 = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str())
    }
    void function()
    {
      // do semthing
    }
    void printFilename1()
    {
      std::cout<<filename1<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is my main function:

```
MyClass *p = new MyClass();
p->setFilename1("first_string");
p->printFilename1();
p->setFilename2("second_string");
p->printFilename1();
```

The output is very surprising to me:

> first_string
>
> second_string

I swear I have no typo in my function MyClass::setFilename2 and I'm not setting the filename2 variable twice.

I'm using the g++ compiler version 4.8.4. Here is how I compile my class:

```
g++ -g -O -Wall -fPIC -pthread -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -m64 -I/home/user/root-6.06.00/include -c myClass.cxx
```

Now, another surprise: when I altered the MyClass::setFilename function:

```
void setFilename2(char* str))
    {
        filename2 = str;
    }
```

I got the output I expected:

> first_string
>
> first_string

Executing the function MyClass::function() doesn't change the value of any of my strings.

So what is going on? This contradicts what I know about C++. How can one function have impact on another if they don't refer to the same variables and have nothing to do with each other?

I suppose it may have something to do with the compiler version or some compiler options. But I have no clue what's going on.

**Edit:** Could you please explain to me why the piece of code behaves the way it does?

Comment: No, it has to do with the incorrect way that you've written the code. You cannot store the pointer returned by `c_str()`. Your class should instead have a member of type `std::string`.

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks, this is a good point. But how can I accept your answer if you posted the comment? And could you explain to me why my code now behaves the way it does? I would expect a crash after the line *p->setFilename1("first_string");*, since the reference I returned won't point to *"first_string"*, which is a temporary object.

Comment: When you find yourself writing `const_cast`... you probably are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c_str()` returns a pointer to a `char` array which is stays valid as long as the `std::string` is not modified; in your case, the `std::string` object over which you called `c_str()` is destroyed immediately after your method returns (it's a temporary object created on the fly from the string literal), so you are effectively storing a pointer to memory that has been deallocated. The fact that you see the new value when you do `printFileName1` is just a side effect of the fact that the allocator is recycling the memory location used before for the other string; as far as the standard is concerned, this all is undefined behavior (and you can expect tragic crashes).

The correct way to go is to store an `std::string` directly inside your class, it will manage its own memory correctly for the whole lifetime of your `MyClass` instance.

```
class MyClass
{
    std::string filename1;
    std::string filename2;
public:
    void setFilename1(std::string str)
    {
        filename1 = str;
    }
    void setFilename2(std::string str))
    {
        filename2 = str;
    }
    void function()
    {
      // do semthing
    }
    void printFilename1()
    {
      std::cout<<filename1<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And could you think of an alternative solution to this problem. It would save me some work if I could store filename1 and filename2 as char* instead of std::string.

Comment: @user2738748 by manually allocating memory for your c-string, copying characters from argument string and making pointer point to allocated memory.

Comment: @user2738748 That sounds extremely unlikely - `std::string` is a way better choice for storage than `char*`.

Comment: @user2738748: exactly how would that save you some work? What are you going to do with `filename1` and `filename2`?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not going to do anything with it. I'm working on an old program. It worked on another computer, but it didn't on mine. I have a newer version of compiler, so I got some warnings. I decided to remove them. One of the problems was that some functions expected char* as an argument and when I tried to use them like that: p->function1("sth"), tehy produced a warning; So I decided that they should accept std::string to get rid of that warning.

Comment: Now I need to find all the variables which should be std::strings in my project and, change their type and add the c_str() function where necessary. This is not lot of work, but I was hoping to avoid that and save some time.

Comment: @user2738748: your remedy is way worse than the original "problem". Probably the only issue in the original code was that they were using `char *` instead of `const char *` to hold pointers to string literals; by introducing those temporary `std::string` now you are introducing serious lifetime errors. Please take the time to learn the language properly before introducing this kind of problems; looking after warnings is ok, but only if you actually know the language, otherwise you are only finding elaborate ways to shut up the compiler without actually solving anything.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks. You're right. But why would adding const to char* help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass *p;
p->setFilename1("first_string");
p->printFilename1();
p->setFilename2("second_string");
p->printFilename1();
```

You never allocate memory for what p points to so anything you call on *p will be undefined behavior

Comment: I do allocate memory for the pointer, I skipped that part in my example.

Comment: @bruffalobill, I just did it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is also wrong for example.

```
void setFilename1(char* str)
{
    std::string buf = str;
    filename1 = const_cast<char*>(buf.c_str())
}
```

Because 'buf' is deleted out of scope.

This is OK.

```
void setFilename1(std::string str)
{
    static std::string buf = str;
    filename1 = const_cast<char*>(buf.c_str())
}
```

other method:

```
class MyClass
{
    char *filename1;
    char *filename2;
public:
    void setFilename1(std::string& str)
    {
        filename1 = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str())
    }
    void setFilename2(std::string& str))
    {
        filename2 = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str())
    }
    void function()
    {
      // do semthing
    }
    void printFilename1()
    {
      std::cout<<filename1<<std::endl;
    }
}

MyClass *p = new MyClass();
string str1 = "first_string";
p->setFilename1(str1);
p->printFilename1();
string str2 = "second_string";
p->setFilename2(str2);
p->printFilename1();
delete p;
```

Comment: Why does adding references help? The string (the reference) is still a temporary object, isn't it?

Comment: { string str("somethig"); } －(same)→{ string* pstr = new string("somethig"); delete pstr;} That exists until 'delete' at the end of scope.